# Reading Address From Memory in C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to store the character at an address in a variable, but I have a compile error ( invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)).

```
int address = 4000;
char character = (char) *address
```

Why doesn't this code dereference the pointer to store the character at memory location 4000 and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing to dereference? You are trying to dereference an `int`. Try `int*` instead. That said, you probably don't know what is at virtual memory address `4000`, so this will likely crash.

Comment: This code doesn't dereference "the pointer" because there is no pointer in your code, just an int.

Comment: you main: char *addres=4000;

Comment: @qPCR4vir: `char *address = 4000;` is a constraint violation. There's no implicit conversion from `int` to `char*`, apart from the special case of a null pointer constant.

Comment: Why do you want to read from address 4000? What do you expect to be there?

Comment: @Keith Thompson. Thank! Constrain violation == compiler error ?

Comment: @qPCR4vir: A constraint violation requires a diagnostic from the compiler (a warning qualifies as a "diagnostic"). The other things that require diagnostics are syntax errors and the `#error` preprocessing directive; the latter is the only thing that requires the compiler to fail.

Comment: @Keith Thompson  Ok. Mean: the literal 4000 is an int. How I write a literal for char* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntactically, you are looking for

```
char character = *(char*)address;
```

Whether this will do anything useful is another matter...

Some issues to ponder:

1. `int` may or may not be wide enough to represent every valid address (on my system, it isn't).
2. How do you know what's at address 4000 in your process's memory map?

Comment: Even if pointers are wider than `int`, converting the `int` value `4000` to a pointer type should give you a pointer to address 4000 -- if that's even meaningful. As the C standard says, "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.".

Comment: @KeithThompson: What I meant was that it may not be possible to represent every address as an `int`.

Comment: True -- but if he knows he wants to read address 4000 (for whatever reason), *that* value is guaranteed to fit in an `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: There's no disagreement about that.

Comment: Perfect answer (along with the comments). Perhaps you should insist a little more on virtual/physical memory to make it clear for the OP ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just attempt to address random memory addresses and expect it to work. Your program may possibly access a non mapped memory address and will just crash or cause yourself many problems later on but to do what you want.

```
char *address = (char *)4000;
char c = *address;
```

Comment: `void *address = 4000;` is a constraint violation. There's no implicit conversion from `int` to `void*` (other than the special case of a null pointer constant such as `0`).

Comment: @KeithThompson you're right I meant `char *` I was writing `void *` in some code I was writing and mixed the two

Comment: There's no implicit conversion from `int` to `char*` either, or to any pointer type. Any such conversion can be done with an explicit cast.

Comment: @KeithThompson I've been using `-fpermissive` for so long I almost forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
/* ... */
uintptr_t ip = 4000;                 // this is an integer
char character = * (char *)(ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
intptr_t address = 4000;
char character = *((char*)address);
```

Comment: @ouah: It's a `(char*)` cast, not a `(char)` cast. It's necessary because there's no implicit conversion from `intptr_t` (an integer type) to `char*` (a pointer type).

Comment: @KeithThompson it was `char character = (char) *((char*)address);` before the edit

Comment: The `(char)` cast was extraneous. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *address=(char*)4000;
char character = *address;
```

yours responsability what is in "4000"

Comment: `char *addres=4000;` is a constraint violation. You need an explicit cast -- or just defer to the other answers.

Comment: @Keith Thompson : is now somewhat better? or just equal?

Comment: It's basically correct now, but it doesn't really say anything that's not already said in the other answers, particularly NPE's. (And you mispelled "address" and "responsibility").